# How to make a function that can use variables dynamically from other functions?

Tags: php

I'd like to know how I can make the following function be able to use variables from other functions..

Other functions will return data(numbers) but I will use the following as an example:

```
$data1 = '25999';
$data2 = '222222'

function roundNumbers()
{
    if ($nData > 999 && $nData <= 999999) {
        $nResult = floor($nData / 1000) . 'K';
    } elseif ($nData > 999999) {
        $nResult = floor($nData / 1000000) . 'M';
    } else {
        $nResult = $nData;
    }
}
```

and then print the data from the function like so: `roundNumbers($data1);` which should show `25K` if `$data1` is used.

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate way to do this would be to pass your value in as an argument to your function, and then return what you have labeled as `$nResult`

This makes the function extremely reusable, and easily tested as it does not rely on any other part of your program. You could even strip it out and put it into its own library for reuse in later applications without concern that it will behave differently.

example:

```
function roundNumbers($nData) {
    if ($nData > 999 && $nData <= 999999) {
        return floor($nData / 1000) . 'K';
    } elseif ($nData > 999999) {
        return floor($nData / 1000000) . 'M';
    } else {
        return = $nData;
    }
}

$data1 = 25999;

echo roundNumbers("25000");
echo roundNumbers($data1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do `$data1`, `$data2`...etc, then you can do:

```
$data1 = '25999';
$data2 = '222222'

function roundNumbers($n)
{ 
    $data_var = "data".$n; //dynamically name the variable
    $nData = $$data_var; //will set $nData into $data1, or $data2 etc depending on $n

    if ($nData > 999 && $nData <= 999999) {
        $nResult = floor($nData / 1000) . 'K';
    } elseif ($nData > 999999) {
        $nResult = floor($nData / 1000000) . 'M';
    } else {
        $nResult = $nData;
    }
}
```